# Server prefix and rails routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, path, prefix

When i'm starting the server with the path option

```
 script/server --path=/myapp
```

while having a route

```
 map.route 'foo', :controller => 'bar', :action => 'buzz'
```

then

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.recognize_path('/myapp/foo')
```

raises an error "No route matched ..."

Question: How can i make Rails built-in routing recognize with path prefix?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Try putting `config.action_controller.relative_url_root = "/myapp"` in environments.rb and start your server normally.

Then Rails will append /myapp/ to all your routes

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a path_prefix available for routes so you can do something like this:

```
map.foo, 'foo', :controller => 'bar', :action => 'buzz', :path_prefix => 'myapp'
```

That should give you a route for /myapp/foo

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot for your answers!

unfortunately i can't use the `:path_prefix` option in `map.foo`, because it's not always the case (the end-user should be responsible for setting or not the prefix while not worring about any routes).

i fingered out following:

```
path = '/myapp/foo'

if relative_url_root = ActionController::Base.relative_url_root
  path.sub!(/\A#{relative_url_root}/i, '')
end

params = ActionController::Routing::Routes.recognize(path)
# => {:controller => 'bar', :action => 'buzz'}
```